# How to Compile TypeScript and SASS Modules to JS/CSS with Relative Import URLs in an Internal Library?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm working on an internal library and I primarily use Parcel for most of my projects. With ESModules becoming the standard in modern JavaScript, I want to compile my TypeScript and SASS into JavaScript and CSS Modules in a specific way. Here's what I'm aiming to achieve:

1. Remove TypeScript types from the output JS files.
2. Update import URLs to be relative. Currently, I'm using a path alias where `~` represents the root project folder.
3. Compile SCSS modules into JavaScript files.

I do not want to bundle everything into a single JS file.

How can I accomplish these tasks while keeping up with the latest best practices? Any tooling suggestions or configuration tips would be appreciated.

Thanks!

P.S.

I realize this post is subjective and liable to be closed due to that fact.

### Things I've Tried

1. WebPack. It seems that this is mostly designed for bundling to one file. TypeScript imports failed during compile because I was telling WebPack to not package node_modules. And it also failed on some imports because they were exported from a package using package.json#exports.
2. Parcel. Compiles to a single file, and there's currently a bug that's breaking the output anyway.
3. ts-patch. This worked fine except for the sass modules. But it also seems like a bad idea since it's patching the typescript compiler code on the fly.